# Phone ports and PC Edition

Tags: dual-boot, windows, ubuntu-touch, android

First of all, Is it possible to install Ubuntu w/ dual boot without formatting my HDD? (Keep in mind partition already been made on HDD).

Also out of curiosity, I have Galaxy s8 and Galaxy Note 3, is it possible to port Ubuntu to these devices?

Any help would be appreciated with installing on Windows

Comment: You may be insterested in visiting this site - https://devices.ubports.com . It continues developing of Utouch.

Comment: You should only ask one question in each question you post, especially when the questions are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm assuming that you're using Windows as your main os. You have to make space on your HDD and then create a new partition there. You can then install Ubuntu on that partition.